# What is the best way to implement multi client server?

Tags: multithreading, server, tcp, client

From TCP based environment, I implement my software like below,

[image]

Actually, it's my first time implementing a network, so I don't know if this is the right way.

When the client connects, the server creates two threads. (Such as send, recv)

- Send thread sends data when data enters the queue, and waits if it is empty.
- Recv thread continuously receives and processes messages (ex. settings) sent by the client.

Currently, the total number of clients I am targeting is 4~5.

This is my sample code,

```
////////////////////////
// Send Thread
while(m_thread_stop_send == false) {    // thread stop flag (when it terminated)
    if(m_sendQueue.empty())    // Queue is memeber variable
        continue;

    // Send data to client
    // until the size of MSG is completely transmitted.
    while(send size < message size) {
        int ret = send(... );
        send size += ret; 
        ...
        if(send size == message size) break;
    }

    // (depending on the MSG) if necessary,
    // Heres recv routine only treat send's ack
    while(recv size < message size) {  // according to packet header
        int ret = recv(... );
        recv size += ret;
        ...
        if(recv size == message size) break;
    }

    m_sendQueue.pop();
}
    

////////////////////////
// Recv Thread
while(m_thread_stop_recv == false) {    // thread stop flag (when it terminated)
    if(alive_flag > 5) // if no alive Msg while 25 sec,
        close socket;
        terminate recv thread
        notify to termination to send thread

    // recv client's message and parsing OP-Code
    switch(OP-Code)
    {
        case A:
            processing...
            and send response to client
            // response was sent directly, without send queue & thread
            send(... response data ...);
        
        case B:
            processing...
            and send response to client
        
        case Alive:    // 5 sec term
            alive_flag = 0
    }
}
```

So I try to these code, but I'm not sure this is correct way ...

Do you have any good examples or open sources of handling Send and Recv continuously, and for each client?

Comment: ` while(send size == message size)` makes no sense. You don't really need the sending thread: you can just send directly rather than enqueing responses.

Comment: Thank you!! first, "send size" means total return of send() function and message size means which i want to send.. for example, when I send 1,000,000 byte jpg image, the "message size" is 1 milion(actually It also contain packet header, but now no consider..)    What "no sense" means is that the actual size sent cannot be clearly identified?

Comment: And, In recv thread, When I was received message, I treat this and then send response directly. The perpose of using send thread is treat server's event. for example, when object was detected, Server need to send this information to client without client's request. So I use "send thread", but I don't know if this is generally the right way. Could you help me some tip for in this case?

Comment: send size can never == message size until *after* a send. So your send loop can never execute. You surely mean `while(send size < message size)`, and you need to initialize `send size` to zero somewhere.

Comment: Oh, that's my mistake. As you said, I implemented the code. Thank you!